# Using stored procedure to send an email from a C# code (correlating C# code into a stored procedure error)

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var stringConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
        var myconnection = new SqlConnection(stringConnection);
        myconnection.Open();

        var myCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_myprocedure", myconnection)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            Connection = myconnection,
            //CommandText = "sp_myprocedure"
        };

        myconnection.Close();
        myconnection.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

My stored procedure works perfectly and sends an email to the recipients, but when I combine it with the C# code it doesn't work. The program doesn't run at all. I am using a web based application of C#.

All I need to do is to send an email to a user. Can I please get help in correlating C# code into MySQL code.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thank you.I will take that note

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually execute the command:

```
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```